# KMZ Polygon not lining up over ArcGIS Pro Basemap

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, kml, basemap, kmz

I have a KMZ file that contains one Polygon drawn around an airport's runway. I used Google Earth to draw the Polygon and the polygon lines up around the runway (see image below).
[image: Polygon drawn using Google Earth]

But when I tried to add this KMZ file to ArcGIS Pro, the polygon does not line-up over the runway, and is off by about 8 feet (see image below).
[image: KMZ file in ArcGIS Pro]

As can be seen in the image in ArGIS Pro, the polygon is offset to the right, by about 8 feet. To get the KMZ into ArcGIS Pro I used the ArcGIS 'KML to Layer' Geoprocessing tool to convert the KMZ file to a layer, and also tried drag-and-drop of the KMZ file over the map.

The Coordinate System of the map in ArcGIS Pro's is 'WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)' and the KMZ Layer's is 'WGS 1984'. My understanding is that ArcGIS does an on-the-fly projection to the KMZ layer's coordinate system. I also tried creating a dummy polygon Feature Class with the coordinate system set to 'WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)', since the ArcGIS Basemaps use this coordinate system. I eventually need to publish this to ArcGIS Online, and this is another reason to use this coordinate system.

How do I get the polygon in the KMZ file to line-up over a Basemap in ArcGIS Pro?

Here is a link to the KMZ file
[KMZ File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17EVkBJop1ySr_Yj8w5LTIn7cJyNRboCU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It's more likely to be that the imagery doesn't line up.

Comment: This sounds a BUG.

Comment: No this sounds like *datum transformation* issue.

Comment: Try opening a new ArcGIS Pro project. Add your runway in WGS84. Reproject the runway layer to the Web Auxillary projection and add this new layer to the project with the basemap. How does it look then?

Comment: I tried the suggestion of @Keagan, but polygon is offset like before. I created a new project with a map, used the 'KMZ to Layer' tool to add the the Runway KMZ file, checked that the Polygon in the Runway layer was 'WGS 1984'. Then used the 'Project' tool to convert to 'WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)', then plotted this to the other project with the basemap.

I've added a link to the Runway KMZ file

Comment: As stated by @user2856, the imagery from ESRI may not line up. Try a different base map...or...digitise the runway from the ESRI Basemap.

Comment: Yes, I think @user2856 explanation of the imagery not lining up may be right. The basemap 'NAIP Imagery Hybrid' does line up, but the basemap 'Imagery Hybrid' does not.

Comment: Yes, aerial & satellite imagery scenes are pretty much never exactly the same, there'll generally be some variation (different sources, different processing/orthorectification or lack thereof etc..).  If you want your imagery to have highly accurate georeferencing, you need to orthorectify with highly accurate ground control points, which is not something you can expect with a world imagery basemap mosaic. You could try adding the NAIP imagery into ArcGIS Pro https://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?sortField=numviews&sortOrder=desc&id=a3fc50066aca4a939f8212af2b88cca6&view=list#content